# Multiple LIKE in PDO query

Tags: php, pdo, sql-like

I need to perform a query on PDO with multiple "likes".

So far I would say my query for 1 like would look like this:
$query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ?');
$query->execute(array('%$value1%'));

So, in case I had this in mysql:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE %$value1% OR column1 LIKE %$value2% OR column2 LIKE %$value1%")
```

How would it translate in PDO?

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?")
$query->execute(array('%$value1%','%$value2%',.....));
```

Would that be good enough?

Comment: Sort your quote style out (variables are not interpolated in single quotes) and yes, that will do fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty much it, although you still appear to be using the `mysql_*` functions rather than PDO in your second example.

Apart from that you'll just need to remember to use double quotes if you want your variables to substitute into the string.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 LIKE ? OR column1 LIKE ? OR column2 LIKE ?');
$query->execute(array("%$value1%","%$value2%",.....));
```